# Get page count in a secured PDF

Tags: c#

I've created a C# application using below codings in order to get pdf page count.

```
public static int GetNoOfPagesPDF(string FileName)
        {
            int result = 0;
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            StreamReader r = new StreamReader(fs);
            string pdfText = r.ReadToEnd();

            System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex regx = new Regex(@"/Type\s*/Page[^s]");
            System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection matches = regx.Matches(pdfText);
            result = matches.Count;
            return result;

        }
```

But I can't get the page count in a protected PDF. How can I get the page count in this kind of a situation.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know exactly how you can find the page count without 3rd part libraries but [`iTextSharp`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) has [`PdfReader`](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfReader.html) class and [`getNumberOfPages`](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfReader.html#getNumberOfPages%28%29) property.

```
public int getNumberOfPages()
Gets the number of pages in the document.
Returns:
the number of pages in the document
```

Here is an example;

```
string path = @"C:\Users\Soner\Desktop\eBook\C#\sample.pdf";
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(path);
int number = reader.NumberOfPages;
```

Comment: I used PdfSharp.dll as 3rd part library. But the problem is it doesn't  work with the protected PDFs.